# added in ngmodule but still getting

Tags: javascript, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWZKA.png)[image]

> ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class SerchPendingPipe in E:/xampp/ht
>   docs/angular_after_merge/source_angular/src/app/pipes/Serch-Pending.pipe.ts!
>   Add SerchPendingPipe to the NgModule to fix it.

Comment: Can you post the Code that throws an error!

Comment: Did you add it to the `declarations` array? Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: Please share the code snippet, how and where have you added it. It should be added to the `providers` array in module

Comment: app.module.ts file in angular 4

Comment: my path is correct but still  getting error @SiddAjmera

Comment: @abhikoshik, add it to module, and import the PIPE, also make sure your appModule declares it so that other modules can use it.

Comment: How we come to know this--> *my path is correct* Post app.module.ts

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal Verifiable Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can create one using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)

Comment: @abhikoshik post the `@NgModule()`

Comment: Add in  `providers: [SerchPendingPipe]` array

Comment: @nircraft i have added code snnipt please check , even i add it into the providers array but still issue not resolve

Comment: Have added an answer! try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app.module.ts` add in declarations array:

```
declarations: [SerchPendingPipe]
```

Your app.module.ts look like:

```
import { SerchPendingPipe} from 'your_path'; // use control + dot to get the IntelliSense

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ..  your components,
    SerchPendingPipe
  ],

  imports: [
    .. Modules
  ],
  providers: [
    .. 
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thankyou @prashant pimpale helping me lot to resolve my issue this answer is correct and even
 checking  this method for solved
import {abc} from 'test/Case/abc';  -- Check case for which is capital for Case word
import {abc} from 'test/case/abc';  -- Check case for which is small for case word

after success build my intialization time also resolved now my site will load in 4-5 sec before that it will take 20-25 sec to load